# rest_sanitize_value_from_schema doesn't sanitize string

Tags: rest-api, validation

This is a part of a simplified piece of code. It accepts a JSON post, validates it against a schema and if ok, sanitize the JSON structure

```
$schema = array(
        'type'       => 'object',
        'properties' => array(
            'email' => array(
                'type'   => 'string',
                'format' => 'email',
            ),
            'name'  => array(
                'type' => 'string',
            ),
        ),
    );

    $json = json_decode( '{"email":"info@test.com","name":"John <script>x.js</script>Doe"}', true );

    $result = rest_validate_value_from_schema( $json, $schema );
    if ( is_wp_error( $result ) ) {
        echo 'Error';
        die();
    }

    $clean = rest_sanitize_value_from_schema( $json, $schema );
```

I'm expecting that the `<script>x.js</script>`part is stripped from the JSON-name field in 'rest_sanitize_value_from schema', but its not happening.

Looking into the function 'rest_sanitize_value_from_schema' on trac (rest-api.php lines 2471) it's obvious why it is not sanitized because all strings are just casted to string!?

```
if ( 'string' === $args['type'] ) {
    return (string) $value;
}
```

Is it me doing something wrong or is it a bug in 'rest_sanitize_value_from_schema'.

Comment: Why do you expect `<script>` to be removed?

Comment: Pretty simple. If you do it this way it is removed: sanitize_text_field( 'John <script>x.js</script>Doe' );

Comment: You're not using that function though. You're using `rest_sanitize_value_from_schema()`, a different function which just sanitises based on the schema, which only declares the value's type, and string value with a `<script>` tag is still a valid string. If you're trying to make a custom REST API endpoint, then you can declare a custom sanitization function when declaring the arguments with `sanitize_callback`. See: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#argument-schema